# Need a regex to remove outer function

Tags: regex, requirejs, sublimetext2

I need to remove require.js from a bunch of files. The rest of the code needs to be preserved, and theres plently of nested functions, etc, which complicates things.  I've pasted a sample below, basically I need 'use strict' to be the first line of code, and also strip the final }); from the code.  Using sublime text 2.  any regex or other ideas how to accomplish this?

EDIT: Need to remove everything before 'use strict' in example below, as well as closing });  Code in between, everything below 'use strict' except for the final closing }); needs to be left in tact.  That code does contain functions and objects which complicate things.  Example of what code may look like:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'common',
    'marionette',
    'bootstrap'
],
function (Backbone, Common) {

    'use strict';

    var foo = 'stuff';

    foo = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        template: 'stuff',

        className: 'more stuff',

        events: {
            "click #a": "s"
        },

        s: function () {

            //
            // On click of a button, hide the modal
            //

            this.$el.modal('hide');
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
.*(?='use strict')|}\);$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iN7uI2/1)**

[image]

Comment: gives me an error that says 'found a closing repetition operator } with no corresponding {

Comment: @user2934565 try to escape curly braces, use: `.*(?='use strict')|\}\);$`

Comment: that gets rid of the error, but if i have any other }); in the code (which I do), it identifies the first one it sees and traverses through matches from there.  Is there any way to match the last one in the document specifically?

Comment: @user2934565 that's because you aren't using the flags I specified in the regex. Noticed that in my screenshot (and also the link) I'm using the flags `g` global and `s` singleline. If you don't use both of them the regex won't work.